# Can Outlook sort mails by deletion date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

Can outlook 2007 sort mails by deletion date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems i posted here too early.

I just found out that sorting the deleted items by modification date achieves the (my) desired effect (since, in most cases, the deletion was the last modification)